# Using pandas under python, how can I plot dates using matplotlib?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have a datframe bankdat with two columns, one with the date in str format, one with floats. I want to use pandas and matplotlib to generate a plot with the x-axis being the dates and the y-axis the floats. I converted the strings to dates using

```
bankdat['Buchungstag'] = pd.to_datetime(bankdat['Buchungstag'])
```

When I now try to plot my dataframe using

```
bankdat.plot()
plt.show()
```

I get numbers instead of dates on my x-axis:

[image: example]

What am I dointg wrong? Thanks for the help
PS: I'm new to coding and stackoverflow and would be very grateful if you pointed out things i got wrong

Edit: Thanks for your suggestions. Unfortunatly, using set index yields this plot:[fig2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0iCOG.png). Am i using different distributions than suggested?

Edit2.
I am getting the dataframe from a csv file using

```
ausgaben = pd.read_csv('asd.csv', encoding = 'ISO-8859-1',sep=';', skiprows=6,usecols=[0,7])
```

after that, i am adding a first row using

```
bankdat = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[np.nan, '10000']]), columns=[ausgaben.columns[0], ausgaben.columns[1]]).append(ausgaben)
```

thanks for pointing out the date ordering, i didnt even get to the "thinking weather my data makes sense" stage. The dataframe looks like this:
[example 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wJStx.png), and exported to csv gives

```
,Betrag (EUR),Kontostand
,4130.96,4130.96
2016-12-23,-65.0,4065.96
2016-12-20,520.0,4585.96
2016-12-19,-29.5,4556.46
2016-09-12,-1000.0,3556.46
```

Solved as per Dmitry Polonskiy's suggestion:" It could be the fact that you have a NAT as the first date in your dates column. Try this bankdat.Buchungstag.shift(1).plot()". Thank you for yoyur help!

Comment: `bankdat.set_index('Buchungstag').plot()` ?

Comment: i edited my question, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
bankdat.set_index(['Buchungstag'], inplace = True)
bankdat.index.name = None

bankdat.Buchungstag.plot(figsize=(10,6), title = 'Title', fontsize = 16)
```

Comment: thanks, unfortunatly the .buchungstag. format doesnt work on my distributions, using bankdat['Buchungstag'] gives me a key error and i have edited my question with the plot i get if i set the index.

Comment: Can you show what the DF looks like? Seems as if there is a problem with the `Buchungstag` column as you state. Also seems as if your dates are in reverse order, you might want to sort your DF so that it is in ascending order.

Comment: Should show the column names and if possible the `bankdat.head()`

Comment: completly misunderstood you, sorry. Edited and thanks!

Comment: It could be the fact that you have a `NAT` as the first date in your dates column. Try this `bankdat.Buchungstag.shift(1).plot()`